# Symfony: Retrieving data from form entity

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to return other data from the entity field from a form type entity.

```
//formtype.php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
        ))
        ->add('field', 'entity', array(
            'expanded'      => true,
            'mapped'        => false,
            'class'         => 'DataBundle\Entity\Names',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->where('p.account = :account')
                    ->setParameters(array(
                        'account' => $this->account
                    ))
                    ;
            },
        ))
    ;
}

//view.html.twig

{% for field in form.field %}
    {{ form_widget(field) }}
    {#{{ prompt.vars.value }}#}
 {% endfor %}
```

I would also like to return for example field file location that is also in the names Entity

so I would have a check box, label and file location returned.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this result you should use the `NamesType` instead of the `entity` type on the form. Create a form for the `Names` entity with the fields you want to display, then embed this form on your form type.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('field', new NamesType())
    ;
}
```

Comment: Using the Type is not going to work because I need to return all of the records as a checkboxes. I just need to return the other columns as well just as information